# Ajax.BeginForm route value which is a model is not updated (values)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ajax.beginform

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTimeShift", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "recordList", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
```

Why is it when i used this overloaded constructor of Ajax.BeginForm above i get the 
updated data in my model but when i used this overloaded constructor below i dont get the updated value of my Model? I need the constructor below in order for me to set the html class attribute of my form...

```
  using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTimeShift", @Model, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "recordList", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
            {


        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { id = "startDate", @readonly = true, width = "100px" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedName, new { id = "selectedName" });
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedUserId, new { id = "selectedUserId" });



        <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Save Time Shift" />
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `Ajax.BeginForm()` has the following method signature:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string actionName, Object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, Object htmlAttributes)
```

Your trying to pass `@Model` as a route value, which isn't how model binding works. The model binder will construct your complex model object via the form values that are posted. Changing your `Ajax.BeginForm()` method to  the following should solve your problem:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTimeShift", new { }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "recordList", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    // Your textboxes, etc corresponding to your model properties go here
}
```